# recover overwritten files

Tags: linux, debian

Have a folder that was working on, and had a previous version on zip, cause the zip file had a different name thought that would create a folder with that name, instead inside the zip was the same folder with the same name, and it had overwritten all my files in the main folder, I had a huge work after that that now seems to be lost, can I recover my files back on this main folder.

Comment: No.  You might want to look into checking if something like git would be appropriate for your workflow for next time.

Comment: Don't you have backups?